# Async Socket Programming. Failed to receive complete data

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, asynchronous

I followed this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx to write this program.

```
    public string ReceiveResponse(Socket client, int bufferSize)
    {
        // Receive the response from the remote device.
        Receive(client, bufferSize);

        // Wait until we receive entire response. 
        receiveDone.WaitOne();

        return response;
    }
```

And my receive callback is

```
       public static void ReceiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        StateObject so = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket s = so.WorkSocket;

        int read = s.EndReceive(ar);

        if (read > 0)
        {
            so.Sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(so.Buffer, 0, read));
            s.BeginReceive(so.Buffer, 0, 1024, 0,
                                     new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback), so);
        }
        else
        {
            if (so.Sb.Length > 1) // Code never reaching this block??
            {
                //All of the data has been read, so displays it to the console 
                string strContent;
                strContent = so.Sb.ToString();
                Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Read {0} byte from socket" +
                                 "data = {1} ", strContent.Length, strContent));
            }
            receiveDone.Set();
        }
    }
```

As commented in my code else block never reaching so my receiveDone manual reset event blocking my unit test forever.

When Microsoft says this is the way to go then why it is not working for me???

I really need it for real time and multi threaded environment. I wasted a lot time on this but couldn't find a proper reason why this is happening? and how I can fix this?

Comment: Youre saying that it never reaches a certain part of your code, im pretty sure it reaches it but the so.Sb.Length is 0. Print the so.Sb.Length on the false just to check what it is. and do you get a socket connect? if so that means that some traffic works. because the code from ms works for me no problem. but do you have a server sunning, the problem might be on that end.

Comment: Its not the reason. I am sure here I am getting data and from my unit test I am reaching first block of the code.

Comment: @VDohnal: Apart from variable names I couldn't notice any..